# The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined. not sure why?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to run my react project and I keep getting this error.
I have reinstalled node and npm, and still this issue persists.
wondering what to do next!

Enclosed, is package.json, hope it will shed some light.

I copied from my github repository the project that was there and I was still getting this error.

```
{
  "name": "our-family-client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@blueprintjs/core": "^3.22.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.4.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.14",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-grid-gallery": "^0.5.5",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "mocha",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^1.13.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^1.13.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^7.0.0",
    "noop-service-worker-middleware": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:117:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:1039:7)
    at noopServiceWorkerMiddleware (/Users/saraginsburg/FlatIron/our-family/our-family-frontend/node_modules/react-dev-utils/noopServiceWorkerMiddleware.js:14:26)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/saraginsburg/FlatIron/our-family/our-family-frontend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/saraginsburg/FlatIron/our-family/our-family-frontend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/saraginsburg/FlatIron/our-family/our-family-frontend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/saraginsburg/FlatIron/our-family/our-family-frontend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/saraginsburg/FlatIron/our-family/our-family-frontend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at launchEditorMiddleware (/Users/saraginsburg/FlatIron/our-family/our-family-frontend/node_modules/react-dev-utils/errorOverlayMiddleware.js:20:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/saraginsburg/FlatIron/our-family/our-family-frontend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/saraginsburg/FlatIron/our-family/our-family-frontend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/saraginsburg/FlatIron/our-family/our-family-frontend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/saraginsburg/FlatIron/our-family/our-family-frontend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/saraginsburg/FlatIron/our-family/our-family-frontend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at handleWebpackInternalMiddleware (/Users/saraginsburg/FlatIron/our-family/our-family-frontend/node_modules/react-dev-utils/evalSourceMapMiddleware.js:42:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/saraginsburg/FlatIron/our-family/our-family-frontend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, this is going to be impossible to debug

Comment: did you check all instructions on the github of the file/package that is throwing an error? https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-dev-utils

Comment: when running npm start, this is what I get

Comment: Provide a chunk of code where you have used path. That would be helpful to debug the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I received this exact error from eslint while running node 10.0

After investigating the call stack, I found a dependency was using a nodejs path module [parameter](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) that was only introduced in nodejs 10.10. 
I was going to open an issue but I checked the eslint documentation and sure enough `Node.js (^10.12.0, or >=12.0.0)` is specified.

I suggest you check your Node.js version and upgrade to at least 10.10

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem for PhantomJS - and what fixed that for me was installing it as an npm package and not system wide.

So - when I ran

`npm i -g phantomjs-prebuilt@^2.1.8`

then phantomjs got installed and is available as a command for my user.

In my case the location for global npm packages without sudo is:

```
$ whereis phantomjs
phantomjs: /home/petar/.npm-packages/bin/phantomjs
```

After that I didn't get the error above and all went fine.

(This way of installing is in contrast to the way I did it before - system-wide, through the package manager or downloading archive and extracting it to /usr/local/bin.)

=====

And last but not least - I found the solution here in [Phantom installation failed TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined #200](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/issues/200) by [Lekensteyn](https://github.com/Lekensteyn).

Comment: pesho hristov, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28951627)

Comment: Thanks, @Shree , for the note. I just updated my answer. Do you think it's OK now? And if so - can you please un-downvode my answer? :)

Comment: @BuddyBob - thank you for the notes, I modified my answer and I think now it's OK and as it should be. If so - can you please un-downvote it? ... If you think it's OK of course :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The issue probably lies within some version of your dev-dependencies related to eslint-config-x or eslint-plugin-x

In our case,
We had 2 projects created from the same starter.
One of the older projects was showing this error but the latest project created from the "updated" starter wasn't showing this error.

So I went ahead with a smart/lazy solution instead of digging down this rabbit hole.
I brought the new "working" config to the older repo and bam.

Here's my `eslint.rc`

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: ['plugin:@next/next/recommended'],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['react', 'import', 'react-hooks'],
  rules: {
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
    'react/prop-types': 'off',
    'import/no-unresolved': [0, { caseSensitive: true }],
    'react-hooks/rules-of-hooks': 'warn', // Checks rules of Hooks
    'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'warn', // Checks effect dependencies
  },
  globals: {
    React: 'writable',
  },
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
      },
    },
  },
}
```

and my dependencies in `package.json`

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "yarn eslint ./src",
  },
  "dependencies": {
  // not really related
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^11.1.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.2",
    "eslint-plugin-json": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the issue was coming from some `eslint-config-x` or `eslint-plugin-x` package, so I just reconfigured eslint from scratch and got rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

In Next.js, if you have added the `plugin:@next/next/recommended` to your eslint config, you will also need to add `eslint-config-next` as a dev dependency:

`npm i eslint-config-next --save-dev`
or
`yarn add -D eslint-config-next`

This also will allow the command `next lint` to run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I tried to pass `undefined` parameter to one of the `path` functions, for example:

`path.join(DIR, 'foo', undefined);`

Try to verify that you dont pass invalid args.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code from your package.json (if you have it)

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "child_process": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  },
```